# Steam Web API: Get CSGO inventory/ CrossDomainRequest

Tags: json, ajax, steam, steam-web-api

I am having issues making the ajax request from my localhost to http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{steamid}/inventory/json/730/2

The issue seems to be that they do not have CORS headers enabled, so I have to use jsonp. Since the GET request returns json, but my ajax function is expecting json-p I receive an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
2?callback=jQuery22005740937136579305_1452887017109&_=1452887017110:1
```

I need this resource, but I am unsure how to get around this. I've looked around on SO, but haven't found anything that matches this issue specifically. There are a few sites that are able to obtain a specific user's inventory, so in some respect it has to be possible.

My Ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198064153275/inventory/json/730/2",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.error){
            alert(response.error_text);
        }else {
            console.log("SUCCESS!!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i just tried adding ?callback=? which i think is the same thing jquery would do, and still did not receive jsonp.  I also tried setting the content type of my request to application/javascript and application/jsonp and did not receive jsonp.  i have played with steam api's a fair bit and i am not sure if you are going to be able to get this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a workaround! I am using django for my web application and so I tried to make the request server side.

I installed the requests library through pip (The library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

In my django app I made a view that would be called by my AJAX request

```
def get_steam_inv(request):
     user_steam_profile = SteamProfile.objects.get(brokerr_user_id = request.user.id)
     r = requests.get("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198064153275/inventory/json/730/2")
     return JsonResponse(r.json())
```

Then my ajax request for this view:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_get_steam_inv/",
    type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            // result = JSON.parse(response);
            if (response.error){
                alert(response.error_text);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
});
```

And now I have the data I needed !